# It is possibile to see my global git histories?

Tags: git

As employee, I would like to see all the commit made during the day thus I can better register my activity in my task manager. It it possibile to see a global history that shows local computer commits (for all repositories in current machine) of a certain period of time?

Comment: You want something besides `git log`?

Comment: Yes, but for all repositories in current machine. Is it possibile?

Comment: `find ~ -name .git` ?

Comment: Too slow. I need to see what I've done today

Comment: git log --oneline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`gr`](https://github.com/mixu/gr):

1. Install it, e.g. via `npm install -g git-run`
2. Configure it, e.g. by [tagging your work repositories with `@work`](https://github.com/mixu/gr#setting-up-tags)
3. Use it, e.g. by running `gr @work git log --since="9am"`